When using TanStack Router's file based routing and createFileRoute, how can I generate a route with underscores in the path?
My auth flow dictates that I handle a callback at ${baseURL}/__/auth/handler.
I'm having difficulty working around the createFileRoute function.
At first I tried placing the page at __/auth/handler.tsx. This resulted in the following Route component:
export const Route = createFileRoute('/_/auth/handler')({   
  component: () => <div>Hello /_/auth/handler!</div>, 
})

Note the missing _ in the route path (presumably stripped by the createFileRoute fn as it is a reserved character).
Then I tried placing the page at /___/auth/handler (NOTE: The extra underscore to 'trick' the createFile Route to assign the right path)
This yielded a better looking Route
export const Route = createFileRoute('/__/auth/handler')({   
  component: () => <div>Hello /__/auth/handler!</div>, 
})

BUT... The routeTree.gen.ts elements are then confused. I get
const AuthHandlerRoute = AuthHandlerImport.update({   path: '/auth/handler',   getParentRoute: () => rootRoute, } as any)
Then in FileRoutesByPath
'/__/auth/handler': {       
  id: '/__/auth/handler'       
  path: '/auth/handler'       
  fullPath: '/auth/handler'       
  preLoaderRoute: 
  typeof AuthHandlerImport       
  parentRoute: typeof rootRoute     
}

Then in FileRoutesByFullPath:
'/auth/handler': typeof AuthHandlerRoute
Then in FileRoutesByTo:
'/auth/handler': typeof AuthHandlerRoute
Then in FileRoutesById:
'/__/auth/handler': typeof AuthHandlerRoute
Then in FileRouteTypes.fullPaths:
'/auth/handler'
Then in FileRoutesByTo.to:
'/auth/handler'
Then in FileRoutesByTo.id:
'/__/auth/handler'
Everything looks OK in the manifest section.
If I manually update these items, the page renders successfully, but the moment I save the file or run the vite dev server all is overwritten.
I'm wondering if there is a way around this. I tried looking into adding in virtual file routes but that didn't seem to help either
